# Mean and Median Image Filtering in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

As a short preamble I'd like to apologize for asking such a positively stupid question.

Now, the proper problem - we're tasked to program a simple Mean/Median (both) Filter for our study program, which will later serve as an introduction and basis for more advanced filter types.

I've studied how the kernel 2D matrix works and flows over the image data matrix (at least, I hope I understand how it's supposed to work), but I'm running into a problem with my code. Each image I filter with the following code shows as a flat colour, usually the first colour from the top-left corner. I'm sure the error is probably tiny, but I just can't seem to find it.

I'd be grateful if you guys could maybe take a look.

```
public void medianFilter(){
        System.out.println("Initializing 2nd image.");
        initializeAltImage(); // <-- Preps a blank image the same size as the original.
        System.out.println("2nd image initialized.");

        int kernelwidth = 3;
        int kernelheight = 3;

        int[] rMedian = new int [kernelwidth*kernelheight];
        int[] gMedian = new int [kernelwidth*kernelheight];
        int[] bMedian = new int [kernelwidth*kernelheight];

        int kerneliter = 0;

        // Walk the entire image but stop before you go out of bounds at the kernel boundraries.
        for (int i = 0; i<this.x-kernelwidth; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<this.y-kernelheight; j++){
                // Walk the kernel itself.
                for (int ki = i; ki<kernelwidth; ki++){
                    for(int kj = j; kj<kernelheight; kj++){
                        Color col = new Color(this.img.getRGB(ki, kj));
                        rMedian[kerneliter] = col.getRed();
                        gMedian[kerneliter] = col.getGreen();
                        bMedian[kerneliter] = col.getBlue();
                        kerneliter++;
                    }
                }
                kerneliter = 0;
                Arrays.sort(rMedian);
                Arrays.sort(gMedian);
                Arrays.sort(bMedian);
                Color colfinal = new Color(rMedian[4], gMedian[4], bMedian[4]);
                this.altimg.setRGB(i+1, j+1, colfinal.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Edit #1: Added full minimal compilable code for help's purposes.

Edit #2: Removed said code. The answer turned out to be simple silly loop limits.

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a full working example. Can you create a minimal compilable example that only requires us to point it at an image file on disk? (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I trimmed down the code just to this base function, and it does reproduce the issue accurately. It's available [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/598kc/ImageMinimal.zip), I hope StackOverflow doesn't mind external hostings. The only downside is that you have to put the image directly into the directory, because I admit I just don't yet know how to program a free-for-all file picker.

Comment: Not many people will download a ZIP file from a sharing site. You should [edit] your question to include the minimal code. Looking at your current code, you don't seem to be far off a minimal example already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the value from the source image `img.getRGB(ki, kj)` you are actually taking a pixel at coordinates between 0 and `kernelwidth`/`kernelheight`.

For simplicity, assume that `kernelwidth=kernelheight=3`. When `i,j >=3` the inner loop is not executed, and the median is not updated.

```
for (int i = 0; i<x-3; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<y-3; j++)
      for (int ki = i; ki<3; ki++)
         for(int kj = j; kj<3; kj++)
             //ki, kj at most between 0 and 2
             img.getRGB(ki, kj)
```

Actually it should be:

```
 for (int i=1; i<x-1; i++)
   for (int j=1; j<y-1; j++)  {
      for (int ki = 0; ki<3; ki++)
         for(int kj = 0; kj<3; kj++)                
            img.getRGB(i+ki-1, j+kj-1) {
            ...
```

Note that I'm not dealing with borders. For the borders you would probably use a reduced kernel, or took values for pixels outside the image as either constant (e.g. white/black) or with the same value as the border.

Comment: Thank you so, so much Javier. This _was_ a retarded problem, I can't believe I completely missed the loop limits being nonsensical. Again, thank you for your time!